# Trying to select every combination from two tables with default values

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table structure like the following:

```
table a:
id int
name varchar

table b:
id int
name varchar

table c:
id int
valid tinyint
table_a int
table_b int
```

Basically, table c maps between table a and b and also has a column to determine if something is valid (either a 1 or 0). I want to be able to select every name (only once) from table a and the linked 'valid' column from table c (and default to 0 if it doesn't exist) and limit it by matching table_b to an id. Hopefully that makes sense.

---

Here is some example data to help show what I mean:

Using the table structure as above I have this data:

```
Table a:
(id, name)
1, row 1
2, row 2
3, row 3

Table b:
(id, name)
1, row a
2, row b

Table c:
(id, valid, table_a, table_b)
1, 1, 1, 1
```

Now, what I want to select is all of the names from table a, the 'valid' column from c (default to 0 if no row that matches) and limit the 'valid' fields by only those that table_b = 1. Hopefully that makes more sense?

So, I want back the following where b.id = 1:

```
(a.name, c.valid)
row 1, 1
row 2, 0
row 3, 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me see if I got it. Are you looking for something like this?

This query:

```
select a.name, coalesce(c.valid, 0) as IsValid, b.id from a
left join c on a.id = c.table_a
left join b on b.id = c.table_b
```

Results in this:

```
NAME    ISVALID ID
row 1   1       1
row 2   0   
row 3   0
```

If you want all `b.id = 1` then you WILL NOT have ALL rows from table_a.

```
select a.name, coalesce(c.valid, 0) as IsValid from a
left join c on a.id = c.table_a
left join b on b.id = c.table_b
where b.id = 1

NAME    ISVALID ID
row 1   1       1
```

Comment: This doesn't limit results by id of table b. But even after adding it, I only get some of the rows from a where there is a link defined in c.

Comment: Yes after adding the where clause, I only get the rows from table a that have a mapping in table c. I need the other rows that don't have a mapping also.

Comment: Ok, create the table structure as above and add this data:

`Table a:
(id, name)
1, row 1
2, row 2
3, row 3

Table b:
(id, name)
1, row a
2, row b

Table c:
(id, valid, table_a, table_b)
1, 1, 1, 1`

Now, what I want to select is all of the names from table a, the 'valid' column from c (default to 0 if no row that matches) and limit the 'valid' fields by only those that table_b = 1. Hopefully that makes more sense?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  a.name,
  IFNULL(c.valid,0) AS valid
FROM
  a
  LEFT JOIN c on a.id=c.table_a
WHERE 
  c.table_b=<your-id-as wanted>
  OR c.table_b IS NULL
;
```

Comment: For me, this doesn't return the whole set of rows from table a, only the ones where there is a row in table c linking them together.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully the query is self explantory:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
  a LEFT OUTER JOIN c ON a.id = c.table_a 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN b ON c.table_b = b.id
WHERE c.valid = 1
```

Comment: This just returns all rows where valid is 1.